# Flask and WTForms - how to get wtforms to refresh select data

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am using the latest version of flask, wtforms and Flask-WTForms.

I have a page that displays a form and one is a select box with option option called "A".

When the app starts all is well.  In a another form I add a record called "B".

Now, the form I want should have the select box wth options A and B bot only option A is available.  I have to kill uWSGI and restart to get wtforms to refresh the data.

So, what am I missing?  How to I get wtforms to refresh data?

Here s how I create the form where getAgencyList returns a list of options to add to the select box.  In another dialogue I add an agency and the agency list should be updated without having to restart the app:

```
class createUser(Form):
    """
    Users are given a default password
    """
    first_name   = TextField()
    last_name    = TextField()
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=120), validators.Email()])
    user_role = SelectField(u'User Role', choices=[('1', 'User'), ('2', 'Admin')])
    org_role = SelectField(u'User Role', choices=[('1', 'Agency'), ('2', 'Advertiser'),('3', 'Admin')])
    agency = SelectField(u'Agency', choices=getAgencyList())
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `getAgencyList()` is called upon definition of the class. So whatever that function returns at that time will be it's data. In order to update the list information you have to somehow run `getAgencyList` during instantiation. In order to do this you can use a not very obvious fact about wtforms that allows you to add choices to a particular field. The [documentation is here](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField) just look for the subsection that is titled "Select fields with dynamic choice values". Here's a sample of code that should work.

```
class CreateUserForm(Form):
    first_name = TextField()
    last_name = TextField()
    email = TextField('Email', 
            [validators.Length(min=6, max=120), validators.Email()])
    user_role = SelectField(u'User Role', 
            choices=[('1', 'User'), ('2', 'Admin')])
    org_role = SelectField(u'User Role', 
            choices=[('1', 'Agency'), ('2', 'Advertiser'),('3', 'Admin')])
    agency = SelectField(u'Agency')

    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        # Instantiate the form
        form = cls()

        # Update the choices for the agency field
        form.agency.choices = getAgencyList()
        return form

# So in order to use you do this ...
@app.route('/someendpoint')
def some_flask_endpoint():
    # ... some code ...
    form = CreateUserForm.new()
    # That should give you a working CreateUserForm with updated values.
    # ... some more code to validate form probably...
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to fetch the options to be displayed from the database and then overwrite the Form Class with those:

eg:

```
def get_agencies():
    agency_list = []
    # get the Agencies from the database - syntax here would be SQLAlchemy
    agencies = Agency.query.all()
    for a in agencies:
        # generate a new list of tuples
        agency_list.append((a.id,a.name))
    return agency_list

@app.route('/somewhere',methods=['POST'])
def somewhere():
    form = createUser()
    # overwrite the choices of the Form Class
    form.agency.choices = get_agencies()
    # here goes the rest of code - like form.validate_on_submit()
    ...
    return render_template('create_user.html', form=form)
```